Product Page Optimization Icon Not Visible
I'm working on a React Native Expo project, and I've run into a frustrating issue. I've been trying to optimize my app's product page on the Apple App Store, but the icon isn't showing up on the Product Page Optimization section. I've double-checked that the icon is correctly set in my app.json, but it still doesn't appear.
Additionally, I'm not sure how to properly add multiple icons for different sizes and scenarios (like iPhone, iPad, etc.) in an Expo project. I've read some documentation, but I'm still confused about how to implement this correctly.
Has anyone else faced this issue, and could you provide some guidance on how to fix the icon visibility problem and how to correctly add multiple icons in an Expo project?
Thanks in advance!
